# Swift NSTableView, NSFileManager, trying to load file names into TableView, and having problems with optionals

Tags: macos, swift, nstableview, nsfilemanager

Trying to load contents of a directory into tableview.

Using: NSFileManager and NSTableView.

Getting Error Message in the last function:

'[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'

Do I miss something regarding Optionals?

Code:

import Cocoa

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

let folderURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("/Applications/")

var error : NSError? = nil

let folderContents: [AnyObject]? = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(folderURL!,
    includingPropertiesForKeys:nil, options:NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions(),
    error:&error)

class tonik: NSObject, NSTableViewDataSource {

```
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
 folderContents?.count
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {
     folderContents[row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it compiles.

I created object in xib file and table view, used the tonik class as datasource for the tableview, now I am getting message:

2015-01-10 07:21:18.420 ac3[6016:143038] *** Illegal NSTableView data source ().  Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:

but both functions are implemented.